# Python - Iteratively generated lambda doesn't work

Tags: python, lambda

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how Python treats and evaluates lambdas at runtime.

### Iteratively building up an integer

Consider the following code (Python 3.5.2):

```
x = 0
for iteration in range(3):
    x = x + 1
print(x)
```

As expected, this prints 3. Here is my understanding of the way x changes over 3 iterations:

- **Initial Value:** `x`
- **Iteration 1:** `x+1`
- **Iteration 2:** `(x+1) + 1`
- **Iteration 3:** `((x+1) + 1) + 1`

### Iteratively building up a lambda

Consider the following code:

```
add3 = lambda x: x
for iteration in range(3):
    add3 = lambda x: add3(x) + 1
print(add3(0))
```

Here is my understanding of the way add3 *should* change over 3 iterations:

- **Initial Value:** `lambda x: x`
- **Iteration 1:** `lambda x: (lambda x: x)(x) + 1`
- **Iteration 2:** `lambda x: (lambda x: (lambda x: x)(x) + 1)(x) + 1`
- **Iteration 3:** `lambda x: (lambda x: (lambda x: (lambda x: x)(x) + 1)(x) + 1)(x) + 1`

Instead, calling add3 causes the maximum recursion depth to be exceeded.
My first thought was that Python is dynamically looking up the function body from its name at call time, rather than storing the function's code as part of the function. However, even the following code does not work:

```
functionList = [lambda x: x] #Store each iteration separately
for i in range(3):
    oldFunction = functionList[-1]
    newFunction = lambda x: oldFunction(x) + 1 #Should be a completely new lambda object
    functionList.append(newFunction)
print(functionList[-1](0)) #Causes infinite recursion
```

Even with no named functions whatsoever, and following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295368/2317852) (although I may have misunderstood his answer), it still fails:

```
functionList = [lambda x: x]
for i in range(3):
    functionList.append(lambda x, i=i: functionList[-1](x) + 1)
print(functionList[-1](0)) #Causes infinite recursion
```

The four lambdas contained in functionList are completely separate objects in memory:

```
>>> print(functionList)
[<function <lambda> at 0x00000266D41A12F0>, <function <lambda> at 0x00000266D41D7E18>, <function <lambda> at 0x00000266D41D7730>, <function <lambda> at 0x00000266D41D7840>]
```

Could someone please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has nothing to do with 'iterational' lambda generation. When you say `add3 = lambda x: add3(x) + 1`, the `add3` object is *replaced* with a lambda *calling itself recursively with no termination condition*.

So when you call `add3(0)`, it becomes:

```
add3(0) = add3(0) + 1 = (add3(0) + 1) + 1 = ((add3(0) + 1) + 1) + 1
```

And this goes on forever (well, until the maximum recursion depth is exceeded).

---

As for other examples, the second function in your list already fails with `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

I've got this code for you:

```
import copy

flist=[lambda x: x]
flist.append(lambda x: copy.deepcopy(flist[-1])(x) + 1)

>>> flist
[<function <lambda> at 0x101d45268>, <function <lambda> at 0x101bf1a60>]
```

So we made sure that we call a *copy* of a function. `flist[-1](0)` results in a `RecursionError`, and the error is raised in the `deepcopy` module. So, this means that `copy.deepcopy(flist[-1])(x)` means 'copy the last element *currently* in the list and run the copy'.

Here it is: the last element of the list calls itself over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up - but how does this explain the infinite recursion even when no lambdas are replaced? Creating a completely new lambda, referencing but not altering the old one, still causes the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it is evaluated at run time.  Because of that, `add3`, when referenced in itself, is calling itself, not the old `add3`.  In the case of your loop, you are always using `[-1]`.  Since it is evaluated at run time, the first one calls the one at the end of the list.  The one at the end of the list then calls the one at the end of the list which calls the one at the end of the list... The list is not changing by the time the functions are being called.  Therefore, the first function is called once, and then the last function is called infinitely.  What you want is to use `[i]` instead of `[-1]`.  It is very good that you used a default argument for `i` in your lambdas because default arguments are evaluated at definition.

Comment: Thank you, this explains the behavior. Using `[i]` instead of `[-1]` resolved the issue. I forgot to take into account that the list lookup is also evaluated at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Python allows you to access variables in the enclosing scope, but you are changing those variables during the loop.

```
add3 = lambda x: x
for iteration in range(3):
    # This add3 will call itself!
    # It always uses the *current* value of add3,
    # NOT the value of add3 when it was created.
    add3 = lambda x: add3(x) + 1
print(add3(0))
```

You will need to create a new binding:

```
add3 = lambda x: x
for _ in range(3):
    add3 = (lambda f: lambda x: f(x) + 1)(add3)
print(add3(0))
```

This creates a new scope each time through the loop, which lets you bind with the current value of `add3` rather than the future value of `add3`.

Languages which behave the way you describe are somewhat rare.  Haskell is one example of such a language.  In C++ you could achieve this by implicitly copying the lambdas using `[=]` for the capture list.  Python just doesn't do this without some extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how `add3` actually changes throughout the loop:

- **Initial Value:** `lambda x: x`
- **Iteration 1:** `lambda x: add3(x) + 1`

`add3` is not immediately substituted inside the lambda body! It gets looked up when the function is executed.

- **Iteration 2:** `lambda x: add3(x) + 1` again
- **Iteration 3:** still `lambda x: add3(x) + 1`

At the end, when you call `add3`, the recursive call to `add3` inside the lambda body looks up the *current* value of `add3`, not the value when the lambda was defined. `add3` calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, and so on until stack overflow.

---

Your attempted fix doesn't work because `oldFunction` *still* gets looked up at function execution time, so it still finds the final `oldFunction` instead of the `oldFunction` from function definition time. You didn't do anything to change that.

---

For comparison, when you do `x = x + 1`, `x` *is* immediately substituted, so in the first version, the values of `x` are successively `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`. You don't have `x = ((x+1) + 1) + 1` at the end; you just have `x = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the name and name binding, the expression `lambda <args>: <expression>` creates a function that equals the result of `def f(<args>): return <expression>`.  The statement `f = lambda <args>: <expression>` does not even have the name binding difference.  However, some people falsely assume other differences.  Many puzzles with lambda are illuminated by replacing it with equivalent defs.  For the code above, we get the following.

```
def add3(x): return x
for iteration in range(3):
    def add3(x): return add3(x) + 1
print(add3(0))
```

Does this make it more obvious that the second def negates the first, by rebinding `add3` to a new function object?  And that executing the second def statement more than once is redundant?  Is it still a surprise that a recursive function with no terminal base case to stop it raises Recursion Error?